# XSLT: How to exclude only a few empty tags from the output?

Tags: xslt

I need to ensure that the empty tags (except the mandatory fields)be excluded from the output. The mandatory fields should be in the output even if they are empty

Using the following xslt, I am able to exclude the empty tags. But even the mandatory fields, if they are empty are removed from the output. Please advise.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match= "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and     
 normalizespace()='']"/>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 <xsl:template match= "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and     
 normalizespace()='']"/>
```

to

```
 <xsl:template match= "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and     
 normalizespace()='' and not(self::foo | self::bar | self::foobar)]"/>
```

where you replace  `foo`, `bar`, `foobar` with the names of your mandatory elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only can end up naming the elements you want to remove:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove the following elements -->
    <xsl:template match="element1 | element2 | element3"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```